# AS3 Audio Effects

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, filter, effects

I want to apply some effects to a sound but I couldn't find one library which has all these effects. Do you know any?

Effects are:

1. Phaser
2. Delay
3. Distortion
4. Cut Filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for.  [SoundFX, out-of-the-box audio filters with actionscript 3](http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/soundfx-out-of-the-box-audio-filters-with-actionscript-3/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know sound libraries are still rather rare for flash. The only one i'm aware of is [this one](http://code.google.com/p/popforge/).